# Is Windows silently uninstalling unused programs?

Tags: windows-10

There are a quite a few programs I need to use only a few times a year.

And regularly, when the time comes, the program I need is nowhere to be found and I have to reinstall it.

At first , I assumed I just forgot to install the programs on this computer, but over time, the issue keeps reoccurring. Am I just getting old and forgetful or is Windows actually ditching some of my programs silently for whatever reason?

Comment: When W10 does one of its major upgrades (eg 1607->1703 or 1703->1709), it sometimes removes programs where it sees compatibility issues. You may have lost your installed programs in this manner: if so, you should be able to find them in the `Windows.old\` directory and this will confirm it. Any removed programs will be recorded in a log somewhere, though I have no idea which.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Windows 10 may remove any of your programs without asking you.

It will only remove programs when updating to a new major version, but it will remove anything it wants starting with small programs and ending with major things like Intel Rapid Storage RAID drivers or USB drivers.

This "feature" is designed to help protect the average Windows user by removing programs considered incompatible, but Windows doesn’t provide any notice that it’s removed a program (Microsoft did not comment on this).

For 30 days after an upgrade you will find your programs in windows.old, but they may not work from there due to registry entries missing.

As a general countermeasure, use portable programs installed in other locations than the windows usual folders.

In the case of older drivers, putting them back is a harder fight (not the topic here).

Comment: Can you add any sources to base your claims?

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but as @ThatBrazilianGuy already said, we should provide an appropriate reference.  Based upon what you said, your answer is taken almost word-for-word from the How-To Geek article:  [Windows 10 May Delete Your Programs Without Asking](https://www.howtogeek.com/243581/windows-10-may-delete-your-programs-without-asking/)

Comment: There are plenty of sources. Here's one that has a common list of removed programs: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/x-programs-windows-10-may-remove-device/ . From a tech point of view, removing SATA drivers or any system driver may lead to disaster.